# Business/Holiday date handling

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a C# class/library that works similarly to the Perl module [`Date::Manip`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip/) as far as business/holiday dates.  Using that module in Perl, I can pass it a date and find out whether it's a business day (ie, Mon-Fri) or a holiday.  Holidays are very simple to define in a config file (see [`Date::Manip::Holidays`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip/Holidays.pod)).  You can enter a 'fixed' date that applies to every year like:

```
12/25                           = Christmas
```

or 'dynamic' dates for every year like:

```
last Monday in May              = Memorial Day
```

or 'fixed' dates for a given year like:

```
5/22/2010                       = Bob's Wedding
```

You can also pass in a date and get back the next/previous business day.

Does anyone know of anything like that in the C# world?  I've found a couple of things that implement parts of what I need (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/busdatescalculation.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/HolidayCalculator.aspx) and I can pick them apart and make what I need.  But if someone else has already done that, why do it again?

Comment: Date::Manip knows when Bob's Wedding is!?

Comment: It does if you define it in the config file!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that did exactly what I wanted so I used the code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/HolidayCalculator.aspx and modified it to fit my needs.  It did most of what I needed so it didn't take much tweaking.

Comment: quite old one now this one

Answer (score 53):

[Nager.Date](https://github.com/nager/Nager.Date) supports over 110 countries (US, DE, FR, RU, UK, ...) the library is available for netstandard2.1. The full list of supported countries can be found [here](https://date.nager.at/Country/Coverage).

## Update 2023

A new [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Holiday) is available. This means that the holidays are now queried by the WebApi and can be easily updated without having to update the NuGet package every time.

**Nuget**

```
PM> install-package Nager.Holiday
```

**Example:**

Get all publicHolidays of a year

```cs
using var holidayClient = new HolidayClient();
var holidays = await holidayClient.GetHolidaysAsync(2023, "de");
```

Check if a date a public holiday

```cs
using var holidayClient = new HolidayClient();
var holidays = await holidayClient.GetHolidaysAsync(checkDate.Year, "de");
if (holidays.Any(o => o.Date == checkDate))
{
    //Yes - New Year's Day
}
```

## Previous answer

**Nuget**

```
PM> install-package Nager.Date
```

**Example:**

Get all publicHolidays of a year

```cs
var publicHolidays = DateSystem.GetPublicHoliday(2018, CountryCode.DE);
```

Check if a date a public holiday

```cs
var date = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01);
if (DateSystem.IsPublicHoliday(date, CountryCode.DE))
{
    //Yes - New Year's Day
}
```

Comment: Cool, working great! Just a notice that after these years the country code parametr seems to have changed from `"DE"` to `CountryCode.DE`.

Comment: Very cool, but note it needs .Net 4.5.

Comment: Seems to be paid now, at least to use it with Nuget.

Comment: Noticed this returns observed dates, are there any options for returning the actual date?

Answer (score 31):

A little late to the party, but figure it will help other people googling it. Found a good answer at http://web.archive.org/web/20210128001521/http://geekswithblogs.net/wpeck/archive/2011/12/27/us-holiday-list-in-c.aspx. It even takes into account holidays that fall on a weekend.

```
private static HashSet<DateTime> GetHolidays(int year) 
{ 
    HashSet<DateTime> holidays = new HashSet<DateTime>();

    // New Years
    DateTime newYearsDate = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 1, 1)); 
    holidays.Add(newYearsDate); 

    // Memorial Day -- last monday in May 
    DateTime memorialDay = new DateTime(year, 5, 31); 
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = memorialDay.DayOfWeek; 
    while (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) 
    { 
        memorialDay = memorialDay.AddDays(-1); 
        dayOfWeek = memorialDay.DayOfWeek; 
    } 
    holidays.Add(memorialDay); 
    
    // Independence Day
    DateTime independenceDay = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 7, 4)); 
    holidays.Add(independenceDay); 
 
    // Labor Day -- 1st Monday in September 
    DateTime laborDay = new DateTime(year, 9, 1); 
    dayOfWeek = laborDay.DayOfWeek; 
    while(dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) 
    { 
        laborDay = laborDay.AddDays(1); 
        dayOfWeek = laborDay.DayOfWeek; 
    } 
    holidays.Add(laborDay);

    // Thanksgiving Day -- 4th Thursday in November 
    var thanksgiving = (from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 30) 
                   where new DateTime(year, 11, day).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday 
                   select day).ElementAt(3); 
    DateTime thanksgivingDay = new DateTime(year, 11, thanksgiving); 
    holidays.Add(thanksgivingDay);

    // Christmas Day 
    DateTime christmasDay = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 12, 25)); 
    holidays.Add(christmasDay); 

    // Next year's new years check
    DateTime nextYearNewYearsDate = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1));
    if (nextYearNewYearsDate.Year == year)
    holidays.Add(nextYearNewYearsDate);

    return holidays; 
}

public static DateTime AdjustForWeekendHoliday(DateTime holiday) 
{ 
    if (holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) 
    { 
        return holiday.AddDays(-1); 
    } 
    else if (holiday.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
    { 
        return holiday.AddDays(1); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return holiday; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Note that depending on your use case, you might need to account for when New Years Day falls on a Saturday. For example 12/31/2010 would be the observed day for 1/1/2011.

Comment: @FacioRatio Look at the AdjustForWeekendHoliday method at the bottom. It takes the holiday's date, then subtracts a day if it is a saturday, and adds a day if it is a sunday.

Comment: Right, but in my case, since the observed day is sometimes in a different year, I needed to account for that. As far as just telling you what the observed holidays are for a given year, though, it worked great for me, thanks!

Comment: @FacioRatio Unless i'm misunderstanding you, the AdjustForWeekendHoliday method should handle your issue as well. DateTime.AddDays() returns a new DateTime of the initial value plus  the number of days passed in. It knows when there is a leap day, new month, or new year. So...                                                                                   
New DateTime(2017,1,1).AddDays(-1) would return (2016,12,31). 

New DateTime(2016,02,28).AddDays(1) would return (2016,02,29). 

New DateTime(2017,02,28).AddDays(1) would return (2017,03,01).

Comment: Continuing on what @FacioRatio was discussing, some New Years Day for certain years do fall on the previous year. For 2011, it is on a Saturday. The holiday therefore is on Friday of 2010.

Comment: @AzzamAziz there are zero cases where DateTime.AddDays() would return the incorrect date. please read my previous comment

Comment: @Todes3ngel it would not return the incorrect date. It works correctly. However, for the year 2010 there is a holiday that falls on 12/31/2010. If you run this code against 2010, it will not show up.

Why? Because that holiday is the result of New Years of 2011 being on a Saturday, which pushes it back one day to 2010.

You will see 12/31/2010 if you run 2011 against the method, but you will not see it if you run 2010 against it.

I hope this explains it well.

Comment: @AzzamAziz ahhhhh, I see what you are saving now. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Todes3ngel, that's what I had sent to be peer reviewed. Do you mind if I add Martin Luther King day as well?

Answer (score 3):

The [drules project](https://github.com/mkdee/d8rules/) is a library that you can use to generate these sort of rules.

The last Monday in May would be:

```
roll(*/5/last, -1, mon)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested by a broad *by country* reference. I am thinking about QuantLib that initially focuses on bank or exchange holidays. You can build the library in C# if necessary altough that might be heavy to do so.

I any case, that's by far the best reference I can find.

[QuantLib: Calendars](http://quantlib.org/reference/group__calendars.html)

Comment: please provide an answer to the question (with an example) and not just a link.

Comment: Please post the main parts of the link in your answer. If in the future that link is broken this answer will be useless

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Business hours calculator which also handles Market Holidays used by financial institutions. It checks for all the 9 Market Holidays and you can tweak your Business hours for weekdays or weekends.

[Business Hours Calculator](http://codechurn.wordpress.com/2013/10/17/how-to-get-business-hours-and-eliminate-market-holidays/)

Answer (score -2):

`Date::Manip` can handle complicated rules, such as good friday.  Here's the definition of good friday in the `Date::Manip` `holidays.cnf` file I use:

```
1*0:0:0:0:0:0*EASTER,PD5    = Good Friday
```

Internally, it has the logic to determine when Easter is based on phases of the moon.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about finding a C# library that could do what `Date::Manip` does.