# get exluding days from database not List

Tags: c#, database, datetimepicker

so here is the thing i have to get end period from date and exclude saturdays and sundays and specific dates from calendar, so i have made it with list but i need to do this with database because i might need to add some addition holidays by the time goes, i have database and everything set up to add i just need to get function which will correctly read dates from database and exclude them

here is code how i made it with list:

```
    List<DateTime> Holidays = new List<DateTime>() 
    { 
        new DateTime(2014, 01, 01), 
        new DateTime(2014, 04, 18), 
        new DateTime(2014, 12, 24), 
        new DateTime(2014, 12, 25), 
        new DateTime(2014, 12, 26),
        new DateTime(2014, 12, 31) 
    };

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    DateTime AddBusinessDays(int days, DateTime starDate)
    {          
        DateTime tempdt = new DateTime(starDate.Year, starDate.Month, starDate.Day);           
        tempdt = ExHolidays(tempdt, Holidays);
        if (tempdt > starDate.Date && !(days == 0))
             tempdt = tempdt.AddDays(-1);
        days = days - 1;
        while (days > 0)
        {
             tempdt = tempdt.AddDays(1);
             // ja sakuma diena ir brivdiena >>> nakamas darbadienas -1
             tempdt = ExHolidays(tempdt, Holidays);
             days = days - 1;
         }          
        return tempdt;            
    }

    DateTime ExHolidays(DateTime startDate, List<DateTime> holidays)
    {
        while (!IsWorkDay(startDate, holidays))
        {
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
        }
        return startDate;
    }

    bool IsWorkDay(DateTime startDate, List<DateTime> holidays)
    {          
        if ((startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||holidays.Contains(startDate)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

here is how i execute it  for example adding 30 working days:

```
dateTimePicker2.Value = AddBusinessDays(30, dateTimePicker1.Value);
```

it all works i just want to be able to add additional holiday dates and i think the best way to do it would be by database

Comment: This link might be of assistance and it is for C#.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709584/business-holiday-date-handling

Comment: nop its not the thing i am searching for.i want to know how to make database work with thouse 3 function basicly i want to replace list with database but all i have tryed aint working

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what holidays you want to show.  Some holidays are fixed, while others are the Xth day of a month.  For instance, Thanksgiving is always the 4th thursday, so you would need a database design flexible enough to capture that, and then build into your application the ability to convert the 4th Thursday into an actual date.

However, the database option is nice because you can only pull back the holidays that exist within the month of dates you are showing ot the user, not having to programmably do that in code.

Comment: yh but the think i am searchin for is just so user can add it by datagridview adn i have it all seted up i just need thouse 3 functions  which adds date to datetimpicker to work with database date column not list cuz i cant create list which will be editable by any user