# Dealing with Holiday Exception in Date Calculation

Tags: c#

I have a report that is run once a year for Top Heavy testing. This report requires running of a Payroll stored procedure with an input parameter of the last payroll run of the prior year.  Employees are paid every two weeks on Friday, so I calculate that with a "seed" date as follows:

```
    public DateTime GetLastPayDayOfYearFromDate(DateTime myDate)
    {
        string myDay = myDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        while (myDay != "Friday")
        {
            myDate = myDate.AddDays(-1);
            myDay = myDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        }

        DateTime mySeedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/1970");
        TimeSpan myTimeSpan = myDate.Subtract(mySeedDate);
        int myDaysDifference = myTimeSpan.Days;
        int test = (myDaysDifference % 14);
        if (myDaysDifference % 14 != 0)
        {
            myDate = myDate.AddDays(-7);
        }

        return myDate;
    }
```

That usually works exactly the way I want it to, but I have run into an unanticipated exception.  If you look at a 2015 calendar, 12/18/2015 is, indeed, the last payroll Friday of 2015, so 01/01/2016 would normally be the payday, but in this case, since 01/01/2016 is a holiday, the company ran payroll on Thursday. Thus the last payroll was actually 12/31/2015, but my code above will not produce that date.

It is rare that something like this will happen, but it DID happen, and the report is inaccurate because of that.  How do we code reliably for such exceptions, and then the inevitable "exception to the exception?"

Comment: I would really appreciate some comment or explanation for the downvote. Drive-by downvotes are completely unhelpful.

Comment: Michael, thanks for catching the mistag.  I had my head in SQL land, but you're correct this is C#.

Comment: while I agree that "drive-by downvotes" are not unhelpful, my guess would be that it occurred because you're basically asking the community to solve your problem without having put any effort into it yourself (beyond stating what the problem is). Most contributors here prefer to see questions where the person has proposed  solution needs help getting that last 20% worked out.

Comment: Question, how would a computer know what a holiday is? Unless you have a list of all holidays somewhere, you're going to need to maintain that list yourself

Comment: At that point, is it worth dealing with these exceptions or is it better to do this manually? It's an interesting question, as people will forget to maintain those holiday dates, I've seen it happen before

Comment: Since holidays are different per country you will have to keep a list with them yourself. Then just check if your date is in the list with holidays and subtract days until you have found a not holiday.

Comment: Speaking of holiday handling, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709584/business-holiday-date-handling) might be a good read, it's got a few people's interpretation on how to handle the issue of holidays, that might give you a good starting position

Comment: Draken, thank you for the link to the other question. I will check that out. Craig W. you could not be further from the truth.  Not only have I worked the issue, the code is posted above.  I am asking about situations where there is an exception to the rule.  I am hopeful that someone with more wisdom and experience could suggest a course of action that I could pursue. I did not ask for anyone to "solve my problem."  In stark contrast, Draken has been helpful, and I have a couple of ideas for resolving this issue going forward.