# If a public holiday falls on a Saturday, I want a button enabled

Tags: vb.net

This code enables the save button so that you can approve the balance, 
but i need it to be enabled even when there is a public holiday, not 
only during the week.

Needs to be enabled on weekends as well

---

```
Sub BindData(ByVal BalanceDate As Date)
    Try
        Dim CAMSClass As New CFPS_BLL.CAMS_Class
        Dim dtList As DataTable = CAMSClass.Get_CAMS_Balancing(BalanceDate)

        If dtList.Rows.Count() = 0 Then
            lblNumRows.Text = "No data found"
            gvAccSumm.Visible = False
            btnSave.Visible = False
            btnUpdate2.Visible = False
        Else
            btnSave.Visible = True
            btnUpdate2.Visible = True
            gvAccSumm.DataSource = dtList
            Dim dRow As DataRow
            dRow = dtList.Rows(0)
            gvAccSumm.DataBind()
            gvAccSumm.Visible = True

            'if date is last day of the previous month, they should still be able to update balances for month end
            If txtDate.Text = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, CDate("01/" & Month(Date.Today) & "/" & Year(Date.Today))) Then
                'lblMessage.Text = "This date is the last day of the previous month"
                btnSave.Enabled = True
                btnSave.ToolTip = "Button enabled to do month end balance"
                btnUpdate2.Enabled = True
                btnUpdate2.ToolTip = "Button enabled to do month end balance"

                'All other days of month, can only capture cams balances for the previous day - 
                'cannot change balances for other days
            ElseIf txtDate.Text < DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Date.Today.Date) Then
                btnSave.Enabled = False
                btnSave.ToolTip = "If this button is not available then you cannot update the balances for the selected day"
                btnUpdate2.Enabled = False
                btnUpdate2.ToolTip = "If this button is not available then you cannot update the balances for the selected day"
            Else
                btnSave.Enabled = True
                btnSave.ToolTip = "click to save"
                btnUpdate2.Enabled = True
                btnUpdate2.ToolTip = "click to save"
            End If
        End If

        CAMSClass = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Business/Holiday date handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709584/business-holiday-date-handling)

Comment: Do you have a list of holidays? .NET doesn't have one. they are all different per country and some country even have holidays randomly determines every year by their government.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict and consider using variables instead of UI controls

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic bullet to this question.  The .NET Date library does not include any way of determining public holidays.  In order to do that, you must create your own calendar of what is considered public holidays for your location, or use a third party library, such as [this one](https://github.com/martinjw/Holiday).

(I've never had to do this, so I don't know how reliable that or any other library is).

Answer (score 0):

Set the local holidays in a `If` sentence:

```
 If Date.Today = ("14/01/2017")  Or Date.Today=("18/01/2017") or ... then
    btnSave.Enabled = True
 End if
```

This just compare the today date with the holidays that you declare in there and enables the Save button.
set this in your loadform.